# How to catch input events from USB joysticks in AS3 (Adobe AIR)?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, joystick

AS3 can catch keyboard events, but how catch usb joystick's input event ?

Comment: aren't USB game controllers just mapped to keyboard keys?

Comment: Yes I think, but with a keyboard event, flashdevelop trace anything else than keyboard's input.

Comment: @2smacks can you show the output you get when you trace the keyboard events you get from your usb game controller input, I didn't understand your last comment.

Answer (score 6):

There are some new packages for this.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/ui/GameInput.html

I haven't gotten around to this yet, but it seems very similar to the keyboard input.

Basically, you have to:

1. Detect the USB controller in flash.
2. Determine what type of inputs the device has (wheel, joystick, touchpad, etc.).
3. Decode the signals from the USB device and create a sort of key-map for your controller.
4. Use the key-map you created in much the same way as keyboard input, but using GameInputEvent listeners instead of KeyboardEvents.

Comment: very nice.  i wasn't aware of this new class.

Comment: `flash.ui.GameInput` doesn't work at all. Any call to properties throws **not defined** error. It seems to be only available in AIR bs.